# Rewriting site permissions in Sharepoint / c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to copy site permissions from one site to another. When I was trying to copy permissions from site which has 6 users added it worked fine, but then I run my code to copy permissions from site with 87 users - result was unexpected. All users were rewriten correctly but many of permissions was wrong (like Web-Admins having View only). Anyone may know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
//ealier here I clear all permissions from destSite (it works fine)
clientContext.Load(sourceSite.RoleAssignments);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
for (int i = 0; i < sourceSite.RoleAssignments.Count; i++)//scource -> dest copy
//foreach (RoleAssignment role in sourceSite.RoleAssignments)
{
     SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
     {
          RoleAssignment role = sourceSite.RoleAssignments[i];

          clientContext.Load(role, r => r.Member, r => r.RoleDefinitionBindings);
          clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

          destSite.RoleAssignments.Add(role.Member, role.RoleDefinitionBindings);
          premCoppied++;
     });

}
```

Comment: While debuging role.RoleDefinitionBindings and role.Members arguments at RoleAssigments.Add() method contain correct values (like Web Site Administrator for Web-Admins) but permissions are still being set wrong.

Comment: I found out that my code do not copy role definitions which are Project Server levels. They are named: "* (Miscrosoft Project Server)" in Sharepoint. Still dont know how  to sort this out.